# Appending an element to the page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What should be the easiest thing to do in Js is giving me a headache. I'm simply trying to append my search bar I created in vanilla js to my page but the console keeps sending errors like *'is null'* or *'Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.'*
Here is the code:

```
var searchBar = function createBar (searchString) {

var studentSearch = document.createElement("div");
var input = document.createElement("input");
var searchButton = document.createElement("button");

input.type="text";

searchButton.innerText="Search";
studentSearch.className = "student-search";

//append these elements to the page
studentSearch.appendChild(input);
studentSearch.appendChild(searchButton);

return studentSearch; }
```

Then I add it to the page onload:

```
var pageHeader = document.querySelector(".page-header");
function addSearchBar () {
    console.log('Adding search bar, trying to anyway...')
    pageHeader.appendChild(searchBar);
}

window.onload = addSearchBar;
```

On the HTML side, my div looks like:

```
 <div class="page-header cf">
    <h2>Students</h2>
  </div>
```

Any help on this? 
Ps: I need to use Vanilla Js, so no jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to invoke the function, to generate the DOM element.

`pageHeader.appendChild(searchBar);`

Should be:
`pageHeader.appendChild(searchBar());`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    var txtNode = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
    if ( typeof txtNode == "object" ) {
        document.getElementsByName("body").appendChild(txtNode);
    }
```

For more help: http://www.w3schools.com/

If you call a function then get in the practice of checking the result to be valid.

Don't use innerText as it isn't supported by all browsers, create a text node as in the above example and append that.

To set attributes like 'class' use the setAttribute method.

```
    el.setAttribute("class", "name of your class");
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you never invoke the searchBar function. e.g. in the `addSearchBar` function, `pageHeader.appendChild(searchBar);` should be `pageHeader.appendChild(searchBar());`. Note the `searchBar` vs `searchBar()`.

Also, I recommend moving the part where you define `pageHeader` into the addSearchBar function because you're setting pageHeader before the `onload` event, and depending on how your page loads and what other things happened on your page before the onload is fired, the `.page-header` node may not exist yet when you set it before the `onload` event.

Here's a working example of your code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/adieuadieu/pen/ozpAja)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, I' try to keep my variables to the top of the page :)